# Asp.Net Windows authentication y forms authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net

La idea o requerimiento es tener una aplicación la cual pueda trabajar al mismo tiempo con Windows y forms authentication.

- Si el usuario que intenta acceder a la aplicación cuenta con credenciales del dominio(intranet) entonces la aplicación otorgar el acceso mediante Windows authentication.
- En caso contrario la aplicación muestra un login utilizando forms authentication.

¿Es posible hacer esto?

Comment: Hola Luis, bienvenido a Stackoverflow en Español. Tu pregunta es muy interesante pero quizás sea demasiado amplia. Intenta aportar mas detalles de tu problema y acotar más el alcance y se pueda responder mejor. Por ejemplo, estas preguntas me planteo yo al leerla, ¿Que versión de .NET estás utilizando? ¿Usas ASP.NET MVC? Que usas para la autenticación, ¿ASP.NET Identity? ¿Membership? ¿A "pelo"? ¿Tus usuarios de Windows también están en la base de datos? ¿como los relacionas? ¿Que sistema de autorización utilizas?... Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Lo que recomendaria es que crees dos sitios web en el IIS

- uno con seguridad integrada con windows
- el otro con seguridad `forms` de asp.net

Entonces el usuario ingresar al primero sitio, si pasa la autenticacion porque puedes detectar en el `Application_AuthenticateRequest` que es un usuario valido del dominio entonces ingresa.

Ahora si no puede autenticar redireccionas al otro sitio que solicita login mediante usuario y password.

[ASP.NET Mixed Mode Authentication](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_security/authentication/article.php/c19559/ASPNET-Mixed-Mode-Authentication.htm)

[IIS7 Mixed Windows and Forms Authentication](http://low-bandwidth.blogspot.com.ar/2014/11/iis7-mixed-windows-and-forms.html)